# How Sentry is cleaned up correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sentry

My sentry version is 22.9.0.

It is downloaded through https://github.com/getsentry/self-hosted.git,Build by docker compose.

I want to clean up historical data to save space.

I checked several methods on the Internet

All are configured by `docker exec -it sentry_worker_1 bash` or `docker exec -it sentry_postgres_1 bash`

But these methods are outdated, I did not find the relevant container in my docker container

Later by viewing the configuration file

Try to modify the configuration of `SENTRY_EVENT_RETENTION_DAYS` in `docker-compose.yml` in the root directory to 7

[docker-compose.yml File Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeuiQ.png)

[Modify content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbLnG.png)

After restarting (`docker compose down`&`docker compose up -d`), about 50G was cleaned up. Then go to the sentry web to check, everything has been cleared, which is obviously wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcbIJ.png)

question

1. How to clean up properly
2. Restart after modifying SENTRY_EVENT_RETENTION_DAYS, why does it still take up so much space

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

```
docker exec -it sentry-self-hosted_postgres_1 bash
psql -U postgres
TRUNCATE TABLE nodestore_node;
```